# Is it possible to disable WinRT app close gesture (Pull app from top to bottom)

Tags: windows-8, dell-latitude, gestures

I want to disable the app closing gesture, pulling app from top to bottom, in my Dell Latitude 10. See the below given image which shows which thing I want to disable.

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to cancel the action midway, or disable the action all together?

Comment: Whatever is possible, my aim is to restrict user to close the app in any way.

Comment: What's the use case for this?  If you're a developer, trying to stop the user from using any other app, you're going to have some pretty upset customers.

Answer (score 2):

Wait for the Windows 8.1 update to get the kiosk mode/assigned access to only allow 1 app to be launched and never be closed.

> Assigned Access: This new Windows 8.1 feature lets organizations
>   enable a single Windows Store application experience on a device so
>   the user only experiences the specified application but cannot access
>   other system files and applications.

Comment: Yes I know about that thing, but is it possible to do same thing in Windows 8 through registry editing or programming a helper app ?

Comment: 8.1 will be a free upgrade to all devices, if you're willing to wait for the official release.  Beta is also available to the public as well.

Comment: wait till October when you get this update for free. There is no buildin way in the original Windows 8.